# Formula for rolling an n-sided die x times without repeats

Tags: combinatorics

I have a gut feeling that there's factorials involved in this, but I'm having trouble simplifying it.

If one rolls an N-sided die X amount of times, what would the formula be for determining the probability of there being no repeats?

Example: Roll a 10 sided die 4 times, the probability of there being no repeats is

$\frac{10}{10} * \frac{9}{10} * \frac{8}{10} * \frac{7}{10}=0.504$.

I thought that it should be
$\frac{10! / 7!}{10^4}$.

But $\frac{10 * 9 * 8 * 7}{10^4} = 0.504$ and $\frac{\frac{10!}{7!}}{10^4} = 0.072$

Comment: You either have some typos or some serious misconceptions.  It will be $\frac{10}{10}\cdot\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{8}{10}\cdot \frac{7}{10}$ exactly as you expected.  Note that $10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7 = \frac{10!}{6!}$, not $10!-7!$.  Note also that $\frac{10!}{7!}=10\cdot 9\cdot 8 \neq 0.072$

Comment: To see this, remember that $n!=n\cdot (n-1)!$, and applying this repeatedly you get $10!=10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot (6!)$.  Dividing both sides by $6!$ gives the result that $\frac{10!}{6!}=10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7$.  If you wish to use cleaner notation, [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) handle this quite nicely, allowing you to write $10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7$ as $10\frac{4}{~}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah I had some typos. I meant $\frac{10!}{7!}$. My misconception was that $10*9*8*7 = \frac{10!}{7!}$.

Answer (score 1):

You take away the factors by dividing. So instead of $10!-7!$, we have $10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7=\frac{10!}{6!}$. I think that's enough for you to finish it from here ;)